# JBPM5.4 - Handling Optimistic lock issue - sessionInfo getting persisted by two calls simultaneously

Tags: jbpm

I have searched the web and seen many people getting similar issue - ksession is getting optimistic lock failure but I have never been able to implement a solution. Here's what I am doing

I am using Jboss AS 7 servers. When the first startProcess call comes, I load and cache the kbase will all workflows that I will use (because loading them every time slows down the system...I have about 20 workflows). I store it in a static variable. From this point on, every time a new session is created (JPAKnowledgeService.newStatefulKnowledgeSession) or an existing session is loaded (JPAKnowledgeService.loadStatefulKnowledgeSession), it reuses the kbase. It all works fine if every thing run in serialized fashion.

I introduced parallel processing using multiple instances node in workflows. It works until two individual calls try to complete their workitems in the common ksession almost at the same time, then i optimistic lock failure. I tried to implement a pessimitic lock on the sessionInfo entity object but didnt work.

I am not able to implement a retry mechanism (tried different ways with cacthing exceptions). Kindly guide me to the right way of using the retry mechanism. If I upgrade to JBPM6.x, will I be able to solve this issue using session per request approach?

Answer (score 0):

You should only get an optimistic locking exception if two you have two sessions with *the same id* trying to persist their changes in parallel (or one is using stale data from the start).  You need to make sure this doesn't happen, either by keeping track of existing sessions (and routing requests for the same ksession to the same instance, not loading the same session data in a different instance) or by simply using different sessions (for example a new one per request, which is possible if you don't maintain any session state (rule data, timers) across requests.

In jBPM6, the new session management strategies do a lot of this out of the box for you, and there's a new retry interceptor that can retry the request in case of real conflict (which should be rare and thus usually hides this issue entirely).  Especially the per request strategy (which now allows you to create / dispose a session per request yet still support long-running timers) would probably work out-of-the-box here.